# How can I enable "copy" in cells under noneditablecolumns on tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to select a specific cell on a noneditablecoulumn and I would like to copy the values in it.
Since the column is under non editable then I cannot even highlight the cell value.

Is there any customization needed?

thanks!

Comment: Could you give more explanation on what you call tabulator?

Comment: This comment is tagged with the Tabulator which is for the JavaScript library, this question makes sense in its current form

Comment: you should be able to select the text content of a cell even if it isnt editable. this suggest that something in your table is mis-configured or you have competing CSS on your page. Could you post a link to a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue so we can understand how your table is set up